# How to understand combination?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$2$ fair tetrahedral dice each showing the numbers from $1$ to $4$ on each of their faces are rolled and their face values are added together. How can I calculate the discrete probability distribution?

My workings:

[image]

[image]

I am struggling to understand the use of combinations. So lets say I want to know the probability of sum of $3$ how can I do that? So I can get $1$ on the first die and $2$ on the second die. and I can get $2$ on the second die first and they can be counted as one? Likewise I can get $1$ on the second die and $2$ on the first die. I can also get $1$ on the second die first or second, either way they counted as one?

Can someone please provide an intuitive way to understand combination? What is I want to calculate the probability of getting a sum of 5?

Answer (score -1):

So the sample space for all possible outcomes of rolling those two dice will be $S ={\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}}$. There are 16 different outcomes of the rolls. Only 1 of them will be equal to $2$ (when you get $1$ and $1$ on both dice), hence probability of getting a sum of $2$ will be $1/16$. To get the sum equal to $3$ you can get either $2,1$ or $1,2$ which means only two different options, so probability of sum $3$ will be $2/16$ and so on. The intuition is to calculate the possible ways of getting the sum and divide that by total possible outcomes.